# A Select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval (No data retrieval involved)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE @a bit;
DECLARE @b bit;
DECLARE @c bit;

SELECT 
    @a = flagA, @b = flagB, 
    CASE WHEN flagC is null then @c = 0 ELSE @c = 1 END
FROM Table
```

The query above throw the exception as stated in the title. Correct me if im wrong but seems to me there is no data retrieval involved in the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the value to `@c` like this:

```
SELECT
    @a = flagA,
    @b = flagB,
    @c = (CASE WHEN flagC IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM table
```